# Word Search ; Burst of life after rain

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I was reading this: https://www.forbes.com/sites/trevornace/2017/09/05/incredible-full-bloom-leaves-worlds-driest-desert-awash-color/

So, i notice, that the desert "bursts into life" after rain.

I would like to find a single word describing the phenomena or "bursting into life" ; or "to become abundant to life after a dry spell".

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How about *blooms*.

Comment: I like "blooms," too. There's also "flourishes," "burgeons," and "thrives," but I don't think any of those hit the nail on the head as directly as "blooms." Now, if you intend to say "bursts BACK into life," you could say "resurrects" or "is reborn." Also, I checked to see if "petrichor," a word for the robust earthy, pleasant, and sweet scent produced by rainfall on very dry ground, to see if it has a verb form that might mean something similar, that odor coming from things "bursting to life," as it were, but no such luck. Sorry.

Comment: Can the word "bloom" be used as a noun? As a word for the phenomena , the emergence of life itself? Thank you

Comment: 'Bloom' can be a noun but it means a single flower, a misting on a polished surface, a healthy glow on a person's cheek or one of a few other less common things. Saying "The bloom on the desert after rain" could be used, especially poetically, but runs the risk, to me, of sounding as though you are talking about a single flower rather than the overall effect.

Comment: @BoldBen I had a similar concern. For this reason, is there a better word to describe the phenomena as a noun?

Comment: Bloom as a noun has certain less positive meanings, such as "a delicate powdery coating on some fruits and leaves", or an excessive growth of algae or bacteria, so using it to mean "flourishing" is problematic, as BoldBen says. Something like "blossoming" or "flourishing" or "lushness" or "verdure" would work better as a noun.

Comment: _A new lease of life_ works well too.

Comment: @user405662 i need a single word

Comment: How would you be using this noun in a sentence?

Comment: @TinfoilHat : say, The Monsoon ______ has arrived. I know it is not monsoon in the desert in the example. But, similar burst of life can be expected after an asian monsoon too.

Comment: For the desert, the noun phrase [*desert bloom*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desert_bloom) is perfect.

Comment: @TinfoilHat : but in general? Say in a dryish- asian country? and single word?